# SharePoint 2010 Mobile Redirection

Tags: redirect, mobile

I have been searching around on the web and can not find anything conclusive. Is it possible at all within SharePoint 2010 configuration to setup per page redirection so that a page visited on a mobile device can be redirected to specific page on an external site? That's then without any custom development.

Would really appreciate any assistance.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Define codeless? No managed code, no JavaScript or what? If you want a script and code free solution you could use a meta refresh in a CEWP ( http://xxx'" />). 
If you can use JavaScript you could check for a mobile device by parsing navigator.userAgent and redirect using window.location.replace(url).

The problems will be that the page will load or partially load before redirecting. Without JavaScript you have no way of detecting the client.

Comment: Ok so the only way is then to embed JS in the pages we want redirected?

Comment: With client detection yes. Without the client detection your options are better.